# How to iterate over array of objects

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am calling a PHP function from a JQuery ajax method. Below is how the response looks from ajax call:

[image]

My question is: how to iterate over this array in jquery to get the values?

I am getting "Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in Array" if I iterate using $.each.

Below is the Code:

```
$("#member_country").change(function() {
        var country = $(this).val();
        //alert(country);
        var ajax_url_mtypes = ins_membership_ajax.ajax_url;                    
        //alert(ajax_url_mtypes);
        jQuery.ajax({
        url:ajax_url_mtypes, 
        data:{country:country, 
        action: "ins_get_membershiptypes_from_country"},
        method:'GET',
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        success:function(response) {
          //var resp = $.trim(response);
          alert(response);
          $.each(response, function( key, value ) {
              alert( key );
              alert( value );
            });              
      }
      });
```

PHP Code:

```
 public static function getMembershipTypesNonAdmin($country){
        $rtn = array();
        global $wpdb;
        $table = $wpdb->prefix.self::TABLE_NAME;
        $query = "SELECT * FROM {$table} where admin_only = 'false' order by member_type";
        $results = $wpdb->get_results($query);
        if($results){
            foreach($results as $row){
                $membership_type = INS_Membership_Types::loadById($row->id);
                $membership_type->setDues(INS_Membership_Types::getDuesByEconomy($country, $membership_type->getMemberType()));
                $rtn[] = $membership_type;
            }
        }
        return $rtn;
    }

    private $dues;

    public function getDues()
    {
        return $this->dues;
    }

    public function setDues($dues)
    {
        return $this->dues = $dues;
    }
```

Comment: `success:function(response) {` - Check if this `response` here is an array, or a string instead.

Comment: You should encode your array to json using json_encode() from your php script. Then it will give proper json in response that you can iterate through

Comment: @Manish: how to check that?

Comment: `typeof response`

Comment: @ManishGiri: I checked. It's a string. How do I get the values now? Even if I give json_encode it is coming as a string

Comment: @Karts It's a string, that's why `$.each()` is not working. If `response` is an array encoded in `JSON`, try `response = JSON.parse(response)` before doing `$.each(response, function( key, value ) {`.
This should extract the array over which you can then iterate.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over objects through for in loop. like as below:

```
for(var prop in object){
console.log(object[prop]);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try with json.
Use

> json_encode()

in the php code and

> dataType: "json"

in the ajax call